# Writing changes to a complex CFPreferences structure

Tags: cocoa, plist

I can easily see how to add hierarchical data to a plist file via the CFPreferences api.

However, whats far less obvious how to read from a CFPreferences a value stored inside a CFDictionary (that might be stored in turn, in a CFDictionary), and change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t, you have to replace the root element. If this is too cumbersome, that’s a sign that you should be using model objects rather than collections and possibly move away from CFPreferences/NSUserDefaults to some other storage mechanism, perhaps Core Data.